# Google Apps Script move completed item to another spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AnVTJLrKrQo_dE5zdTlKbmxkRk1PU19HUnBlTFBBMWc&hl=en&authkey=CLOYpKoH

I'm working on a script that will help me keep track of receipts for customer orders. It is in google docs spreadsheet.

If you click the above link you can see what I am talking about. You can access the script in the toolbar Tools>Scripts>Script Editor

I need the script to move the receipt to another sheet when it is completed. I have that function pretty much working right now. Is there a way to have the completed sheets filed alphabetically by the customer's name? If anyone has a few minutes and can have a look at the script it would be very very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are putting together a hacked solution for a problem that's been solved by greater minds with more money and more time.

http://www.google.com/search?q=free+invoice+online

http://www.google.com/search?q=free+crm